# Given an integer, add operators between digits to get n and return list of correct answers

Tags: python

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve:

> Given an `int, ops, n`, create a `function(int, ops, n)` and slot operators between digits of `int` to create equations that evaluates to `n`. Return a list of all possible answers. Importing functions is not allowed.

For example,

```
function(111111, '+-%*', 11) => [1*1+11/1-1 = 11, 1*1/1-1+11 =11, ...]
```

The question recommended using `interleave(str1, str2)` where `interleave('abcdef', 'ab') = 'aabbcdef'` and `product(str1, n)` where `product('ab', 3) = ['aaa','aab','abb','bbb','aba','baa','bba']`.

I have written `interleave(str1, str2)` which is

```py
def interleave(str1,str2):
    lsta,lstb,result= list(str1),list(str2),''
    while lsta and lstb:
        result += lsta.pop(0)
        result += lstb.pop(0)
    if lsta:
        for i in lsta:
            result+= i
    else:
        for i in lstb:
            result+=i
    return result
```

However, I have no idea how to code the `product` function. I assume it has to do something with recursion, so I'm trying to add `'a'` and `'b'` for every product.

```py
def product(str1,n):
    if n ==1:
        return  []
    else:
        return [product(str1,n-1)]+[str1[0]]
```

Please help me to understand how to solve this question. (Not only the product it self)

Comment: What you're looking for is the power set; it is strange that the question calls it a product. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Algorithms

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're asking: do you just want to write `product` or are you asking how to solve the whole algorithm? They're pretty distinct questions. Thanks! FYI, the problem is similar to [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/expression-add-operators/description/).

Comment: Does product really return a *sum* ?  It'd seem more reasonable to return `['aaa', 'aab', ...]`, i.e. the list of all possible triplets made with a and b

Comment: @ggorlen Hi, I am asking how to solve the entire algorithm. It is just that the question gave these function to help but I am unable to see any relationship to it.

Comment: @Demi-Lune Apology I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### General solution

Assuming your implementation of `interleave` is correct, you can use it together with `product` (see my suggested implementation below) to  solve the problem with something like:

```py
def f(i, ops, n):
    int_str = str(i)
    retval = []
    for seq_len in range(1, len(int_str)):
        for op_seq in r_prod(ops, seq_len):
            eq = interleave(int_str, op_seq)
            if eval(eq) == n:
                retval.append(eq)
    return retval
```

The idea is that you interleave the digits of your string with your operators in a varying order. Basically I do that with all possible sequences of length `seq_len` which varies from 1 to max, which will be the number of digits - 1 (see assumptions below!). Then you use the [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#eval) `eval` to evaluate the expression returned by `inteleave` for a specific sequence of the operators and compare the result with the desired number, `n`. If the expression evaluates to `n` you append it to the return array `retval` (initially empty). After you evaluated all the expressions for all possible operator sequences (see assumptions!) you return the array.

#### Assumptions

It's not clear whether you can use the same operator multiple times or if you're allowed to omit using some. I assumed you can use the same operator many times and that you're allowed to omit using an operator. Hence, the `r_prod` was used (as suggested by your question). In case of such restrictions, you will want to use permutations (of possibly varying length) of the group of operators.

Secondly, I assumed that your implementation of the `interleave` function is correct. It is not clear if, for example, `interleave("112", "*")` should return both "1*12" and "11*2" or just "1*12" like your implementation does. In the case both should be returned, then you should also iterate over the possible ways *the same ordered* sequence of operators can be interleaved with the provided digits. I omitted that, because I saw that your function always returns a single string.

#### Product implementation

If you look at the [itertools docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) you can see the equivalent code for the function `itertools.product`. Using that you'd have:

```py
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)

a = ["".join(x) for x in product('ab', repeat=3)]
print(a)
```

Which prints `['aaa', 'aab', 'aba', 'abb', 'baa', 'bab', 'bba', 'bbb']` -- what I guess is what you're after.

A more specific (assuming iterable is a string), less efficient, but hopefully more understandable solution would be:

```py
def prod(string, r):
    if r < 1:
        return None
    retval = list(string)
    for i in range(r - 1):
        temp = []
        for l in retval:
            for c in string:
                temp.append(l + c)
        retval = temp
    return retval
```

The idea is simple. The second parameter `r` gives you the length of the strings you want to produce. The characters in the string give you the elements from which you build the string. Hence, you first generate a string of length 1 that starts with each possible character. Then for each of those strings you generate new strings by concatenating the old string with all of the possible characters.

For example, given a pool of characters "abc", you'll first generate strings "a", "b", and "c". Then you'll replace string "a" with strings "aa", "ab", and "ac". Similarly for "b" and "c". You repeat this process n-times to get all possible strings of length r generated by *drawing with replacement* from the pool "abc".

I'd think it would be a good idea for you to try to implement the `prod` function recursively. You can see my ugly solution below, but I'd suggest you stop reading this now and try to do it without looking at my suggestion first.

---

SPOILER BELOW

---

```py
def r_prod(string, r):
    if r == 1:
        return list(string)
    else:
        return [c + s for c in string for s in r_prod(string, r - 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I still do not get that recursion below but I will keep on trying to figure out.